# Android App not opening using AppLinks

Tags: android, applinks

I am working on adding meta properties to my page as introduce in [applinks.org](http://applinks.org), however **my app is not responding to the web url**, here is the html source:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta property="al:android:url" content="applink://url" />
    <meta property="al:android:package" content="com.applink.sample" />
    <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="Sample" />
</head>
<body>
Hello!!
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the intent filter I'm having:

```
<activity
            android:name=".play.StartAppLinkActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.CATEGORY.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data android:scheme="applink"
                    android:host="url"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: where are you clicking the url from?

Answer (score 0):

`<category android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.CATEGORY.BROWSABLE"/>` should be changed to `<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>`. Manifest is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Please do following changes in web change `al:android:url` content

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta property="al:android:url" content="http://applink/url" />
    <meta property="al:android:package" content="com.applink.sample" />
    <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="Sample" />
</head>
<body>
    Hello!!
</body>
</html>
```

and in manifest do this

```
<activity android:name=".play.StartAppLinkActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>    
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="applink" android:path="/url"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="applink" android:path="/url"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```